# Moltin Javascript issue: moltin.Cart.Complete returns 406 not acceptable

Tags: javascript, angularjs, moltin

Using the Moltin Javascript SDK and able to retrieve products and add them to my cart. However when I try to checkout the cart and process a payment I get a 406 Not acceptable returned.

This I have stripped out all my two way binding and used the code snippet from Moltin's site but still not result.

Link to the entire project as well https://github.com/humbm0/ecommerce-site.

Thanks in advance!

```
angular.module('ecommerceSite2App')
.controller('CheckoutCtrl', function ($scope, checkout, moltin) {
$scope.items = checkout.cart.contents;

$scope.createOrder = function() {

  var order = moltin.Cart.Complete({
    gateway: 'dummy',
    customer: {
      first_name: 'Jon',
      last_name:  'Doe',
      email:      'jon.doe@gmail.com'
    },
    bill_to: {
      first_name: 'Jon',
      last_name:  'Doe',
      address_1:  '123 Sunny Street',
      address_2:  'Sunnycreek',
      city:       'Sunnyvale',
      county:     'California',
      country:    'US',
      postcode:   'CA94040',
      phone:      '6507123124'
    },
    ship_to: 'bill_to',
    shipping: '1305214549095350548'
  });
  console.log(order);

  var checkout = moltin.Checkout.Payment('purchase', order.id, {
    data: {
      number:       '4242424242424242',
      expiry_month: '02',
      expiry_year:  '2017',
      cvv:          '123'
    }
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked that you have enabled the dummy gateway from the forge dashboard? - https://forge.moltin.com/gateway

The second thing, instead of using the shipping method ID could you try using the shipping method slug instead?

If you need more help you can also request an invite to join our community slack channel where you can speak to other users and the rest of the moltin team. https://moltin.com/community

Comment: Perfect thanks! Spent so long trying to debug previous code turned out I had forgot to enable the dummy gateway. Not obvious in the getting started instructions or docs that this needs to be done.